# String condition in List<T>

Tags: c#

I have a class named `HomeInfo`

```
public class HomeInfo
{
   public int ID {get;set;}
   public string OwnerName {get;set;}
   public string Address {get;set;}
   public int EstimatedValue {get;set;}
}
```

I get data from server and i add that into `List<HomeInfo> listHomeInfo`

Now in my GUI I need to allow filtering results based on user input, so my client wants a textbox for Estimated Value and he wants to enter text there like '>30k and <50k' or '>50k', I parsed and converted these values and created object of class

```
public class ExpressionValue
{
    public float? FirstDigit { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// >, >=, <,<=
    /// </summary>
    public string FirstExpCondition { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// OR, AND
    /// </summary>
    public string ConditionOperator { get; set; }
    public float SecondDigit { get; set; }
    public string SecondExpCondition { get; set; }
}
```

Using an ExpressionValue object I am able to create a proper condition string.
Now I am able to create a condition string like 'EstimatedValue > 30000 AND EstimatedValue < 60000' or 'EstimatedValue < 50000'

I don't know how can I effectively apply this condition on 'List listHomeInfo' since as far i know `List<T>.Where()` doesn't support string condition. I know a way around it is to convert the list to DataTable and use `Select(string expression)` method and then convert `DataRow[]` to `List<HomeInfo>`, but I think there may be a better way to achieve this.

[EDIT]

I created two methods to help me out but i am getting exception "The binary operator GreaterThan is not defined for the types 'System.Single' and 'System.Double'." when creating BinaryExpression.

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> ParseExpressionCondition<T>(string expression, string fieldName)
    {
        try
        {
            string decimalNumRegex = @"\d+(\.\d{1,2})?";
            List<string> matchPatterns = new List<string>() { ">=", ">", "<=", "<" };
            ExpressionValue expValue = new ExpressionValue();
            Dictionary<string, string> conditions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), typeof(T).ToString());
            //var lhs = Expression.GreaterThan(Expression.Property(parameter, "EstimatedValue"), Expression.Constant(30000));
            BinaryExpression lhs = null, rhs = null;
            object objectValue = null;
            string condOperator = null;
            foreach (string pattern in matchPatterns)
            {
                Match match = Regex.Match(expression, pattern + decimalNumRegex);

                if (match.Success)
                {
                    //get digit part
                    double digit = double.Parse(Regex.Match(match.Value, decimalNumRegex).Value);
                    if (!expValue.FirstDigit.HasValue)
                    {
                        objectValue = digit;
                        condOperator = match.Value.Replace(digit.ToString(), "");
                        lhs = GetBinaryExpression(parameter, fieldName, objectValue, condOperator);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        objectValue = digit;
                        condOperator = match.Value.Replace(digit.ToString(), "");
                        rhs = GetBinaryExpression(parameter, fieldName, objectValue, condOperator);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (expression.ToLower().Contains("and"))
                return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.And(lhs, rhs), parameter);
            else if (expression.ToLower().Contains("or"))
                return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Or(lhs, rhs), parameter);


            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.WriteLog(ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    private static BinaryExpression GetBinaryExpression(ParameterExpression paraExp, string fieldName, object expressionValue, string conditionOperator)
    {
        try
        {
            BinaryExpression binExp = null;
            MemberExpression expressionLeft = Expression.Property(paraExp, fieldName);
            Expression expressionRight = Expression.Constant(expressionValue );
            switch (conditionOperator)
            {
                case ">":
                    binExp = Expression.GreaterThan(expressionLeft, expressionRight);
                    break;
                case ">=":
                    binExp = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(expressionLeft, expressionRight);
                    break;
                case "<":
                    binExp = Expression.LessThan(expressionLeft, expressionRight);
                    break;
                case "<=":
                    binExp = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(expressionLeft, expressionRight);
                    break;
            }
            return binExp;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to store the condition as a string?  Is it entered by the user?  Why not use an expression tree?

Comment: `List.Where() doesn't support string condition` -- Sure it does, if a `string` is what you're evaluating in your condition.

Comment: This example doesn't look like it needs such a high degree of customization in putting the query together, but there is always the [dynamic LINQ library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have parsing logic already implemented to some extent, I would suggest generating an expression tree (rather than using your own custom `ExpressionValue` class).

E.g. 'EstimatedValue > 30000 AND EstimatedValue < 60000' could become an expression tree of the form:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(HomeInfo), "homeInfo");
var lhs = Expression.GreaterThan(Expression.Property(parameter, "EstimatedValue"), Expression.Constant(30000));
var rhs = Expression.LessThan(Expression.Property(parameter, "EstimatedValue"), Expression.Constant(60000));
var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<HomeInfo, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(lhs, rhs), parameter);
```

The list can then be queried using the generated expression tree as follows:

```
var results = listHomeInfo.AsQueryable().Where(expression);
```

Comment: +1 because I'd never heard of expression trees and I now love you  ;-)!

Comment: @Iridium I created two methods to help me out but i am getting exception "The binary operator GreaterThan is not defined for the types 'System.Single' and 'System.Double'." when creating BinaryExpression.

Comment: @DineshAhuja The problem is that one side of your Expression.GreaterThan() is a double, the other side is a float (single). The float won't be automatically upcasted to a double to permit the comparison (as it would be if you were comparing floats and doubles directly), so you need to do it manually. I would suggest you start by trying to replace the "double digit = double.Parse(Regex.Match(match.Value..." (from the code in your edit) with "float digit = float.Parse(Regex.Match(match.Value..." (i.e. parse the value as a float instead of a double).

Answer (score 0):

Do not reinvent the wheel: [NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/) does that kind of stuff already.

With a variable named `EstimatedValue` and a user defined expression `UserExpression`, in NCalc you'd do:

```
myList.Where(elem => new Expression(EstimatedValue.ToString() + UserExpression).Evaluate());
```

Answer (score 0):

In your position I'd create a mini rule engine.

So

```
public abstract class ExpressionBase {
 public float value {get;set;}
}

public class GreaterThanExpression : ExpressionBase {}
public class LessThanExpression : ExpressionBase {}
```

Now as you parse the entered string you can build a list of the expressions entered and then apply them to an IQueryable in the order you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Write a LINQ extention method....

```
public static IEnumerable<HomeInfo> PassesExpression(this IEnumerable<HomeInfo> homes, ExpressionValue expression)
{
    foreach(HomeInfo home in homes)
    {
        bool one, two;

        if(expression.FirstExpCondition == '>')
            one = (home.EstimatedValue > expression.FirstDigit);
        else if(expression.FirstExpCondition == '>=')
            one = (home.EstimatedValue >= expression.FirstDigit);
        else if(expression.FirstExpCondition == '<')
            one = (home.EstimatedValue < expression.FirstDigit);
        else if(expression.FirstExpCondition == '<=')
            one = (home.EstimatedValue <= expression.FirstDigit);

        if(expression.SecondExpCondition == '>')
            two = (home.EstimatedValue > expression.SecondDigit);
        else if(expression.SecondExpCondition == '>=')
            two = (home.EstimatedValue >= expression.SecondDigit);
        else if(expression.SecondExpCondition == '<')
            two = (home.EstimatedValue < expression.SecondDigit);
        else if(expression.SecondExpCondition == '<=')
            two = (home.EstimatedValue <= expression.SecondDigit);

        if((expression.ConditionOperator == 'OR' && (one || two)) || (expression.ConditionOperator == 'AND' && (one && two)))
            yield return home;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually have two textboxes for value ranges. One for the minimum value, one for the maximum value. They can be empty, if the limit is not required

```
int? min = null
int? max = null;
int i;

if (Int32.TryParse(txtMin.Text, out i) min = i;
if (Int32.TryParse(txtMax.Text, out i) max = i;

string name = txtName.Text;
```

With these definitions you can combine where clauses dynamically

```
IEnumerable<HomeInfo> result = list;
if (min.HasValue) result = result.Where(h => h.EstimatedValue >= min.Value);
if (max.HasValue) result = result.Where(h => h.EstimatedValue <= max.Value);
if (name != "")
    result = result.Where(
        h => h.OwnerName.StartsWith(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    );
```

Comment: So you plan to do this for each different possible property value, and each possible comparison operator?  I don't think it will scale that well.

Comment: @Servy: I revised my solution, meanwhile. It combines predicates dynamically.

Answer (score -1):

use LinqToObjects

```
List<HomeInfo> homeInfos = new List<HomeInfo>();

homeInfos.Where(x => x.EstimatedValue > 1000).Where(x => x.EstimatedValue < 10000);
```

Comment: The filtering needs to be based on user input, not hard coded compile time vales.

Comment: You need to assign the result of the expression to a variable; `Where` does not modify the original list, and the result will be lost with this code.

Comment: I don't know how can I effectively apply this condition on 'List listHomeInfo' since as far i know List<T>.Where() doesn't support string condition             At the end of the day, he wants to apply the conditions to the list rather than use the expression conditions, use LINQ he can sort this out easily.